# oracle associative array of associative array of records

Tags: oracle, associative-array

I am using Oracle's associative array in package specification as below

```
TYPE type1
IS
  RECORD
  (  A NUMBER(3,0),
     B VARCHAR2(2 BYTE),
     C NUMBER(3,0)

   );

TYPE type2 IS TABLE OF type1 INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;

TYPE type3 IS TABLE OF type2 INDEX BY VARCHAR2(10); 

PROCEDURE proc1 (v_type3 OUT NOCOPY type3);
```

and i have to access them in body in body

when I am using

```
v_type3('ABC').type2(1).A :=5;
v_type3('ABC').type2(1).B :='test';
```

It is giving me compilation error that type 2 is not declared/undefined.

How can I access each element in body?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't usually need to mention the type of a variable before indexing it, so I think what you need is

```
v_type3('ABC')(1).A :=5;
v_type3('ABC')(1).B :='test';
```